# AWS Glue Error "Path does not exist"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Every time I try to run some very simple jobs (import json on s3 to Redshift) I get the following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist:
>   s3://my-temp-glue-dir/f316d46f-eaf3-497a-927b-47ff04462e4a;'

This is not a permissions issue, since I have some other (more complex jobs with joins) working reliably. Really not sure what the issue could be - any help would be appreciated.

I'm using 2 DPU's, but have tried 5. I also tried using a different temp directory. Also, there are hundreds of files, and some of the files are very small (a few lines), but I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the cause of this error is simply the number of files I'm attempting to load at the same time (and that the error itself is misleading). After disabling bookmarks, and using a subset of the data, things are working as expected.

Comment: You can check if your dynamic frame has data with this command: `applymapping1.toDF().show()`

Comment: I think it's because of `bookmarks`, I got a similar error when the `bookmarks` is `enabled`, and it seems disappeared after I disabled it. Not sure why, hoping someone can give us some more inputs.